# Huge data IE, slow translate3d

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, translate3d

Im using this plugin 'SidebarTransitions by codrops' for making a sidebar-menu..

For show/hiding the menu, its using this translate3d css

```
.st-effect-1.st-menu {
 visibility: visible;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
 transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}

.st-effect-1.st-menu-open .st-effect-1.st-menu {
 visibility: visible;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

My problem is when i fill the site with alot of data, like 20000 rows in a table, the translate3d effect becomes really slow in IE (using 10 or 11 atm), takes like 5-10sec to do the effect and uses a 100% cpu core..

The same effect in Chrome appears instantly, why? what to tweek for IE to work?

Comment: show your code and markup as well

Comment: mm it dosnt make sence to post a table with 20000 rows.. I cannot make a jsfiddle either since 20000 rows makes it laggy and wierd

Comment: Just the table structure off course :) and a row or two ...Not the entire table if it holds 20000 rows :)

Comment: @AP87 Internet Explorer doesn't handle massive documents all that well right now (we're doing work to fix this). The most helpful bit of advice I could give right now is to explore another solution that doesn't involve tens of thousands of rows to a table in the document. I had to imagine 20,000 rows is simply impractical for human-interaction.

Comment: @davidkonrad its just a normal table <table><tr><td> x alot  :)

Comment: IE has a well known problem when adding to the dom and calculating height / width. I guess there is endless calls to clientHeight and so on. Try hide the container/table if it is IE, and show it then you have inserted the rows for proof of concept.

Comment: @davidkonrad display:none to the table fixes the issue yes

Comment: I suspected it :) gr8 you got it to work!

Comment: @AP87, please provide and accept an answer or delete this question.